# How to visually choose files to add to git by first filtering and then selecting

Tags: git, user-interface, filter

I want to start tracking with git a visual foxpro project that has several thousand files.  They live in a directory tree together with other files that are not part of the project.

Is there an easy and visual way to pick which files files to add (and perhaps remove at some later date)?  Ideally I'd like to filter files by extension and first letter, or perhaps by directory, and pick the ones to add (or remove).

Thank you in advance,

Alex

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`git add --interactive` can help you to add / remove files interactively.

the online help `git help add` has a section "INTERACTIVE MODE" for details

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am looking for something more visual to avoid mistakes.  Ideally a mover between two lists or a list with checkboxes.

Comment: if you are on unix based system, maybe gitk and git gui can help you. On windows, try tortoiseGIT

Comment: Thank you Asenar.  I'll check tortoiseGIT